# jQuery url.indexOf is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, webpack-2

I have just installed jQuery using

```
npm install jquery
```

After merging jquery,bootstrap in a vendor file using Webpack , I am keep on getting following error

```
vendor.4b59d15129c2efa4408c.js:9979 Uncaught TypeError: url.indexOf is not a function
    at jQuery.fn.init.jQuery.fn.load (vendor.4b59d15129c2efa4408c.js:9979)
    at Object.<anonymous> (bundle.7beebbf8c43d73f31563.js:55)
    at Object.<anonymous> (bundle.7beebbf8c43d73f31563.js:213)
    at __webpack_require__ (vendor.4b59d15129c2efa4408c.js:55)
    at Object.<anonymous> (bundle.7beebbf8c43d73f31563.js:12)
    at __webpack_require__ (vendor.4b59d15129c2efa4408c.js:55)
    at webpackJsonpCallback (vendor.4b59d15129c2efa4408c.js:26)
    at bundle.7beebbf8c43d73f31563.js:1
```

Comment: And where's your code?

Comment: I have updated now

Comment: why are you overwriting jQuery's [`load`](http://api.jquery.com/load/) function?

Comment: I am not overwriting any function if you can clt+f and type url.indexof in latest jQuery 3.2.1 you will see the same function as i mentioned in jsfiddle here is the link http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-3.2.1.js

Answer (score 15):

What is your jQuery version? On version 3, the function `$(window).load()` is deprecated. When using `.load()`, `.unload()`, or `.error()` it will throw an error.

Replace those function with:

**old**

`$(window).load( function () {} )`

**version 3 above**

`$(window).on('load', function () {} )`

`$(window).on('error', function () {} )`

my own case was using SuperSimpleSlider jQuery plugins with `Vue.js`. I have to replace the original file (the plugins) with correct solution.

Hope this helps!

Source:
[jqueryhouse.com](https://jqueryhouse.com/jquery-3-0-fix-url-indexof-is-not-a-function-error/)

Answer (score 1):

I suppose that url is a string, so i deduce that is a problem when you set url, try to find that line and replace with console.log(url) to see if it is defined.

Comment: or console.log(typeof(url))

Answer (score 0):

Change this in your code:

```
off = url.indexOf( " " );
```

to:

```
off = url ? url.indexOf( " " ) : -1;
```

In short, you are trying to access `indexOf` on `null` or `undefined`, which throws that error. So what I do is check if url exists, then access indexOf, otherwise set to -1 which is what `indexOf` would return if url doesn't contain the empty string.